# Angular 6 - Interceptor Preflight (CORS)

Tags: angular, cors

I'm using interceptor to activate spinner in each request.

Example interceptor:

```html
 return next.handle(req).do(evt => {
      if (evt instanceof HttpResponse) {
         this.spinnerService.close();
      }
});
```

The req.method is not returning OPTIONS. The request is POST and OPTIONS in browser,but when printed in console log both, are the same.

**Browser**: Request "OPTIONS" and "POST".

**Log in callback interceptor:** "POST" and "POST"

Does anyone have an idea how detect when the request method is OPTIONS? I need to disable the spinner, only when it is not preflight.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with req.method you can access to http method.
Here the request object reference [angular doc](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest)

Comment: The req.method is not returning OPTIONS.The request is POST and OPTIONS in brower,but when printed in console log both, are the same.

Comment: this is because the option call in this case is made automaticaly by browser for security reason (CORS) and you can not handle that.
in this case you have to handler also the exception scenario and stop spinner and maybe sent to user a message about that.